# Android Xml Design Tool Cannot Preview The Widget of AbstractComposeView's Child Class?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

This is my code, a class of AbstractComposeView. But it cannot show on the xml design tool.
And The xml design tool shows the error message:

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewTreeLifecycleOwner not found from androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout{3deb8822 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-0,0}
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposer_androidKt.createLifecycleAwareViewTreeRecomposer(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:244)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposer_androidKt.access$createLifecycleAwareViewTreeRecomposer(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:1)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposerFactory$Companion$LifecycleAware$1.createRecomposer(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:99)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposerPolicy.createAndInstallWindowRecomposer$ui_release(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:155)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposer_androidKt.getWindowRecomposer(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:230)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.resolveParentCompositionContext(ComposeView.android.kt:244)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.ensureCompositionCreated(ComposeView.android.kt:251)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.onAttachedToWindow(ComposeView.android.kt:283)
at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:20753)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3490)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:57)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:368)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:436)
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:121)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:736)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$7(RenderTask.java:892)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$2.run(RenderExecutor.kt:187)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)**

```
class StarLightBoardView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : AbstractComposeView(
    context,
    attrs,
    defStyleAttr
) {

    var starLight by mutableStateOf(0)

    var onAddStarClick by mutableStateOf<() -> Unit>({})

    override var shouldCreateCompositionOnAttachedToWindow: Boolean = false
        private set

    init {
        shouldCreateCompositionOnAttachedToWindow = true
    }

    @Composable
    override fun Content() {
        StarLightBoardView(
            modifier = Modifier.size(R.dimen.dp_113, R.dimen.dp_30),
            starLight = if (isInEditMode) 10 else starLight,
            typeface = when {
                isInEditMode -> Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD
                else -> AppGlobalConfig.getNumberFontTypeface(context)
            },
            onAddStarClick = if (isInEditMode) fun() {} else onAddStarClick
        )
    }
}
```

Thanks for your answer, can you help me to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. The only fix that I found that worked was to get rid of the class inheriting from `AbstractComposeView` and to instead use a `ComposeView` which can't be inherited from. That means that you will have to move the logic out of your `StarLightBoardView` class and into whatever class that contains it, and then call `setContent` on the `ComposeView` object.

```
<LinearLayout
  ...

  <!-- Use ComposeView here rather than your Custom `StarLightBoardView` -->
  <androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
    android:id="@+id/myComposeView"
    ... />

/LinearLayout>
```

And move this logic of yours:

```
var starLight by mutableStateOf(0)

var onAddStarClick by mutableStateOf<() -> Unit>({})
```

into the containing class

Comment: Do you get the preview showing the corresponding content for the ComposeView with this approach?

Comment: @JCarlosR yes I did

Comment: Thanks. For that we need to declare `tools:composableName`.